# How to display youtube videos in recylerview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-youtube-api

I have List of youtube video urls, I want to display these videos in recylerview using YoutubePlayer api. When user click on the video then it should start playing that video.
How to do that? Is there altarnative to do this without using recylerview?
Thanks.

Comment: What did you try so far? I'd probably use https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayerView and if you want a list then recyclerview is the way to go.

Comment: You can try with `WebView` as well.